# Add character before all numbers in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to add a `*` before every number in a string.

```
/-200,/-    -->   /-*200,/-
```

I tried using `.replace(/0/g,'*0'), .replace(/1/g,'*1') ...` but that did not work for multiple digit numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.replace(/(\d+)/g, "*$1")
```

That is, match each instance of one or more digits with `\d+` - where `\d` matches any digit and `+` means one or more. And use parentheses to make it a capturing group so that you can refer to the match in the replacement string as `$1`.

```js
console.log("/-200,/-".replace(/(\d+)/g, "*$1"))
console.log("100, 200, 300".replace(/(\d+)/g, "*$1"))
console.log("A number: 123; a second number: 321".replace(/(\d+)/g, "*$1"))
```